# How to set up PHPUnit test framework without running on Dev server?

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, tdd, phpunit

I don't have control of the Dev server, and may not be able to install or use PHPUnit on it. I installed PHPUnit 3.6 locally on my machine and it requires requires PHP 5.2.7 (or later). But the Dev server is running PHP 5.2.4.

What is the proper way to set up TDD and PHPUnit without running the tests on the dev server? Is it good enough to just run tests locally? Do I need the same versions of PHP and MySQL on the my local machine to do it effectively? (I have MySQL 5.5.16 installed, Dev server is 5.0.xxxx).

Or can I create a some kind of pseudo-unit test to run on the Dev server to make sure that there are no differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you want the same environments across servers, but yes, it is good enough to run the tests locally. Note that PHP 5.2.x has reached end of life. You should update to a 5.3.x version if possible.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. I don't have any control of what happens on the live servers...but installed PHP 5.3.8 on my machine.

Comment: @BSeven bad idea. Like I said, you want *the same environments across servers*. If that's not possible, try to get *as close as possible*. 5.3.8 and 5.2.4 are worlds inbetween with many subtle changes and bugfixes. If your tests suceed on 5.3.8 chances are they wont on 5.2.4. Another option would be to set up a virtual server on your machine and replicate the server environment there for testing.

Comment: What about MySQL and Apache? Do I need to run the same versions locally as on the production server?

Comment: @BSeven same answer as above: *as close as possible* ;) you dont want to risk a change from one version to the other to go unnoticed on your dev environment but lay waste to your production site on deploy.